# Non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

I've got a problem with this code, it should count the longest substring of the same letter in a string, but there is an error:

```
*** Exception: test.hs:(15,0)-(21,17): 
Non-exhaustive patterns in function countLongest'
```

I know that is the wrong types problem, but i dont know where is the error, or how to find or debug it

```
countLongest :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int
countLongest' :: (Eq a) => Int -> Int -> [a] -> Int

countLongest a = countLongest' 0 0 a
countLongest' n max (y:x:ys)
        | y == x = countLongest' (n+1) max (x:ys)
        | n > max = countLongest' 0 (n) (x:ys)
        | otherwise = countLongest' 0 (max) (x:ys)
countLongest' n max []
        | n > max = n
        | otherwise = max
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the case where there's a one element list:

```
countLongest' n max (y:ys)
    | ... etc. ...
    | otherwise = ....
```

---

Here's a contrived example similar to yours:

```
f [] = 3         -- matches an empty list
f (a:b:bs) = 4   -- matches a list with at least two elements
```

Examples:

```
Prelude> :load myfile.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( myfile.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> f [3]
*** Exception: myfile.hs:(3,0)-(4,13): Non-exhaustive patterns in function f

*Main> f []
3
*Main> f [1,2,3,4,5]
4
*Main>
```

So it succeeds with 0 and 2 elements in the list, but fails when there's exactly one element.

---

Note that this behavior is **not** unique to lists.  Here's an example using `Maybe`:

```
g :: Maybe x -> x
g (Just x) = x
```

Examples:

```
*Main> g (Just 4)
4
*Main> g Nothing 
*** Exception: myfile.hs:6:0-13: Non-exhaustive patterns in function g
```

This happened because there's two constructors for `Maybe`, `Just <something>` and `Nothing`.  We didn't provide a case for `Nothing`, so when we passed that into `g`, it didn't work!

---

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737650/better-exception-for-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-case) and its answers for information on getting a little help from the compiler.  I followed the advice of the first answer, and when I loaded my examples, this is what happened:

```
prompt$ ghci -fwarn-incomplete-patterns

Prelude> :load myfile.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( myfile.hs, interpreted )

myfile.hs:3:0:
    Warning: Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
             In the definition of `f': Patterns not matched: [_]

myfile.hs:6:0:
    Warning: Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
             In the definition of `g': Patterns not matched: Nothing
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

Cool!  The compiler is pretty smart!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you need to match for if there is 1 element left in the recursion, for example:

```
countLongest' n max (y:ys)
```

Because the first one matches if there are 2 or more elements left and the last only matches if there is no element left.