# Haskell - Non-exhaustive patterns in case

Tags: list, haskell, case, non-exhaustive-patterns

I have got the following code:

```
F (S core ps) = FAll core [] ps
  where
    FAll core acc ((name, (pc : pcs)) : ps) 
       = case F' (pc : pcs) (readC pc core) core of
            Nothing -> 
                        if (length pcs) /= 0 then FAll core ((name, pcs) : acc) ps

                        else FAll core acc ps


            Just (core', [pc']) -> let
                                     pc'' = pc' `mod` coresize
                                     pcs' = pcs ++ [pc'']
                                   in  FAll core' ((name, pcs') : acc) ps
stepAll core acc [] = S core (reverse acc)
```

It compiles fine but when I run the program it gives the following error:

Melon.hs:(172,10)-(182,74): Non-exhaustive patterns in case

where the number indicating the rows are the ones from the "= case F' (pc : pcs) (readC pc core) core of" to the "in  FAll core' ((name, pcs') : acc) ps"

I think the problem is in exhausting the pattern for (pc : pcs) but I just cannot understand how I can solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

The code has been updated with this one:

I wrote the following:

```
Just (core', (pc' : pcs')) -> let
                                  pc'' = pc' `mod` coresize
                                  pcs' = pcs' ++ [pc'']
                              in  stepAll core' ((name, pcs') : acc) ps
Just (core', []) -> stepAll core acc ps
```

but the program just falls into an infinite loop :S

Comment: I suspect the revised code has an algorithm bug unrelated to the case checking, but without having any idea what your code is doing (and being a little confused about what some of it means, since there seem to be capitalized identifiers where I wouldn't expect) I'm not sure what to advise.

Comment: The infinite loop is due to `pcs' = pcs' ++ [pc'']`. Both `pcs'` in this equation are the same, a new variable shadowing the identically named one from the `Just` pattern, thus you try do define `pcs'` in terms of itself, which gives an infinite loop if `pcs'` is ever demanded. You probably wanted `let ... pcs'' = pcs' ++ [pc''] in stepAll core' ((name,pcs'') : acc) ps`.

Comment: Oh, I misread it as `pcs ++ [pc'']`, same as the other case. Yeah, I expect that's why you're getting an infinite loop.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435575/non-exhaustive-patterns-in-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737650/better-exception-for-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-case

Answer (score 8):

"Non-exhaustive patterns" means that you have a set of pattern matches that don't cover all possible combinations. In your code, you have cases like the following:

```
case {- stuff -} of
    Nothing ->               -- etc.
    Just (core', [pc']) ->   -- etc.
```

You handle both patterns for the `Maybe` portion, and the pair only has one pattern, but you match only on *a single-element* list, so this will fail for patterns that would look like `Just (core', [])` or `Just (core', (pc' : pcs'))`.

It's usually best to handle all possible cases (i.e., have exhaustive pattern matches) even when you expect that some cases will never happen. If you're really, really certain that a case is impossible, then use something like `error "this will never happen because blah blah blah"`. If you can't explain why it'll never happen, then you should consider handling it properly. :]