# Haskell take first and seventh

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

I need to write a function in Haskell that given a list of at least 7 elements returns a tuple containing the first and seventh element.

e.g.

```
Prelude> take1and7 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
(1, 7)
```

I've tried this

```
take1and7 :: [a] -> (a, a)
take1and7 [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, xs] = (a, g)
```

But it says that it has "non-exhaustive patterns" which I don't understand

Comment: you want `take1and7 (a:b:c:d:e:f:g:xs) = (a, g)` instead. (Would be happy to explain further if needed, but I see an answer has gone up since I started typing this :) )

Comment: Do you have to use pattern matching? An easier to read implementation would be to use `!!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell - Non-exhaustive patterns in case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451653/haskell-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
... [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, xs] = ...
```

is a pattern which matches an 8 elements long list. `xs` names the 8th element, not the rest of the list.

In case you call this function with a list of 6, 7, 9, etc. elements, the pattern won't match.

```
... (a: b: c: d: e: f: g: xs) = ...
```

is a pattern which matches a list of 7 elements or longer. `xs` names the *rest* of the list after its first 7 elements. With it, the function still won't be able to handle any list shorter than 7 elements.

The "non-exhaustive" phrasing means our function doesn't handle *all* possible cases.

Comment: I'm now getting a new error  `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    • In the pattern: a : b : c : d : e : f : g : xs
      In the pattern: [a : b : c : d : e : f : g : xs]
      In an equation for ‘take1and7’:
          take1and7 [a : b : c : d : e : f : g : xs] = (a, g) `

Comment: NB: `(a : xs)`  round parens .

Comment: @Huddlespith looks like you misread the code in the answer. You should use`(` and `)`, not square brackets. You can construct a list with either square brackets or the `:` operator, but it's rarely a good idea to use both.

Comment: You still need to indicate what the function should "return" if you *don't* get a list with 7 or more items, if you want to avoid the non-exhaustive pattern warning. That could be as simple as `take1and7 _ = error "List has too few elements"`.