# Exception : Pattern Matching failure Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

I am trying to implement Standard words function of Haskell. I am using State Monad to solve the problem.

My Code is :

```
type WorS = ([String],String,String)

words' :: State WorS [String]
words' = do
           (lwords, words, x:xs) <- get
           case x:xs of
           (' ':xs) -> (put (words:lwords, [], xs) >> words')
           ([]) -> return lwords
           (_:xs)-> (put (lwords, words ++ [x], xs) >> words')

run_word' ::  String ->[String]
run_word' x = reverse $ fst (runState words' ([], [], x))
```

When I do:

```
run_word' "guns and roses"
```

I get this error:

```
Exception: Pattern match failure in do expression
```

The code is loading in ghci without any error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-exhaustive patterns in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435575/non-exhaustive-patterns-in-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
       (lwords,words,x:xs)<-get
```

`x:xs` matches a list with at least one element (`x` becomes the first element, and `xs` becomes the rest of the list), so you get a pattern match failure when the third member of the tuple is `[]`.

Solution: replace

```
       (lwords,words,x:xs)<-get
       case x:xs of
```

with

```
       (lwords,words,xs)<-get
       case xs of
```

(And consider using different variable names later in the function: it gets confusing when you have two or more variables with the same name.)

**Edit:** if you turn on warnings (pass the `-Wall` flag to ghc/ghci), you will get warned at compile time that the pattern may fail to match at runtime. (You'll also get a warning about having one `xs` variable hiding another `xs` variable, called shadowing.)

Comment: I did not get what is wrong in the code. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Every time you iterate through the loop, the list in the third element of the state gets shorter. When it becomes the empty list, you get the pattern match failure.