# Haskell override function

Tags: haskell

I try to write a function to check whether two vectors are equal or not:

```
Compare Vec1 [1, 2, 3]   Vec1 [1, 2, 4]
Compare VecS ["a","b", "c"] VecS ["a", "b", "d"]
```

However, on my function I have "almost" identical implementation for both cases,

is there a way to **simplify** my code so that it has only one implementation for Integer and String

```
data MyVector = Vec1 [Integer] | VecS[String]  

eqAssert::MyVector->MyVector->Bool
eqAssert (Vec1 []) (Vec1 []) = True
eqAssert (Vec1  _) (Vec1 []) = False 
eqAssert (Vec1 (x:cx)) (Vec1 (y:cy)) =
  if length (x:cx) /= length (y:cy)
    then False
    else (if x /= y then False else eqAssert (Vec1 cx) (Vec1 cy))

eqAssert (VecS []) (VecS []) = True
eqAssert (VecS  _) (VecS []) = False 
eqAssert (VecS (x:cx)) (VecS (y:cy)) =
  if length (x:cx) /= length (y:cy)
    then False
    else (if x /= y then False else eqAssert (VecS cx) (VecS cy))
```

Comment: I think you make the comparisons rather hard to begin with.

Comment: The answers below suggest the right solution. However, you should turn on warnings! Above you missed the case `eqAssert (Vec1 []) (Vec1 (x:xs))`, making your program crash when the first list is shorter -- warnings can spot this for you. Further, there is no reason to check for the length, since it is implied by the other checks. Finally, your `if`s are hard to read, and could be replaced by `... && ... && ...`.

Comment: On the warnings chi mentions, see also: [*Better exception for non-exhaustive patterns in case*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737650/better-exception-for-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you aim to do too much work yourself. Haskell has an `Eq` typeclass, and an equality check `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> a` function for that.

Furthermore in Haskell for every `a` such that `Eq a` holds, it also means that `Eq [a]` holds. In that case the equality check is done on lists such that two lists are equal given these have the same number of elements, and if we enumerate the two lists in parallel, each element of the first list is equal to the corresponding element in the other list.

So wen can simplify the function like:

```
eqAssert :: MyVector -> MyVector -> Bool
eqAssert (Vec1 a) (Vec1 b) = a == b
eqAssert (VecS a) (VecS b) = a == b
eqAssert _ _ = False
```

So the function has three clauses. The first one deels with two `Vec1`s, in that case we check the equality of the two lists `a` and `b`. The second clause is almost identical, except that we check for two `VecS`s. Finally we use `eqAssert _ _`. Here `_` is a wildcard: it matches everything. The remaining patterns are `(Vec1 a) (VecS b)` and `(VecS a) (Vec1 b)` regardless what `a` and `b` are, we simply return `False` in that case.

It is furthermore a bit odd to implement an `eqAssert` here. We can make it *automatically* an instance of `Eq`, in that case Haskell will implement an `(==)` function for `MyVector` automatically. So we can write:

```
data MyVector = Vec1 [Integer] | VecS[String] deriving Eq
```

and then use `myvec1 == myvec2` instead.

Comment: N.B. this is exactly the function that `deriving (Eq)` would write for you.

Comment: @luqui: yes, although that would imply that we make it an instance of `Eq` and furthermore that we thus loose the freedom to implement `(==)` in another way. But you are right.

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of the fact that both `Integer` and `String` are `Eq` instances, and for all `Eq a`, `[a]` is also an instance of `Eq`.

You you can pattern-match the lists out of their data constructors and compare them:

```
eqAssert :: MyVector -> MyVector -> Bool
eqAssert (Vec1 xs) (Vec1 ys) = xs == ys
eqAssert (VecS xs) (VecS ys) = xs == ys
eqAssert        _         _  = False
```

Why not make `MyVector` an instance of `Eq`, though?